# Correct way of removing trait objects from container

Tags: rust

Is it correct to remove trait objects by using trait method that casts object address to usize as in this example? Or is there some more safe/idiomatic way?

```
trait IObserver {
    fn update(&mut self, message: &str);
    fn addr(&self) -> usize;
}

impl IObserver for Observer {
    fn addr(&self) -> usize {
        self as *const Self as usize
    }
    // ...
}

struct Subject {
    observers: Vec<Rc<RefCell<dyn IObserver>>>
}

impl Subject {
    fn unsubscribe(&mut self, observer: &dyn IObserver) {
        let pos = self.observers.iter().position(|x| {
            x.borrow().addr() == observer.addr()
        });
        if let Some(p) = pos {
            self.observers.remove(p);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I guess what you want is [`std::ptr::eq()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.eq.html) in order to compare addresses (not values).

Comment: You want [`Vec::retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain) which removes all items that do _not_ match the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

According to this comment it is important to cast to `*const ()` before comparing raw pointers to data (discarding vtable pointer)

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/46139#issuecomment-346971153

So then the right code should be:

```rs
fn unsubscribe(&mut self, observer: &dyn IObserver) {
    self.observers.retain(|x| {
        let p1 = x.as_ptr() as *const dyn IObserver as *const ();
        let p2 = observer as *const dyn IObserver as *const ();
        !ptr::eq(p1, p2)
    });
}
```

ptr::eq doesn't do any cast, so it is possible to compare fat pointers, but the result can be unexpected in this case:

> Comparing trait objects pointers compares an vtable addresses which are not guaranteed to be unique and could vary between different code generation units (https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#vtable_address_comparisons)